# Highlight // TODO in XCode

Tags: xcode, comments, syntax-highlighting, highlight, todo

XCode 4 recognizes comments like `// TODO: comment` or `// FIXME: comment` and displays it in the Class overview drop-down.

Is there the possibility to highlight `// TODO` with a bright color in the source code, so one can quickly find open TODOs?

Comment: Check this question:[TODOs in Xcode: How to make them stand out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469412/todos-in-xcode-how-to-make-them-stand-out)

Answer (score 16):

You may be able to edit the syntax highlighting definitions to do this, I am not sure though.

But here is a solution that will [make your TODOs and FIXMEs show up as warnings when you build](http://deallocatedobjects.com/2011/05/11/show-todos-and-fixmes-as-warnings-in-xcode-4/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not quite what I'm looking for though. It should just "detect" `// TODO` and highlight it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `#warning` keyword in your code.