# TODOs in Xcode: How to make them stand out?

Tags: xcode, comments, todo

I am aware of the method of making them warnings, but I want to keep my legit warnings separate from my todos. <strike>I'm also have yet to see xcode 4 highlight the todos like everyone seems to think it does.</strike> And xcode's todo support only works on todos outside of functions...

The build phase script that is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238289/429082) is wonderful, but it makes the TODOs into warnings, and Objective C creates enough legitimate warnings that I don't want my todo's clogging up the list. Is there a way to make the todo's a *different* build result, like an info result or something? Something that will not make Xcode's *real* warnings (half of *should be* errors) vanish in the crowd?

Comment: Has your question been answered to your satisfaction? If so you might want to accept an answer or if not, update your question or add some comments.

Answer (score 20):

#### UPDATE

As of Xcode 4.4; **`FIXME:`**, **`???:`**, **`????:`**, **`!!!:`** all work outside of a function/method.

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER (< Xcode 4.4)

[xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) will highlight a `TODO` but only outside of a function.

```
//TODO: This will show in function drop down 
-(void)method1
{
    //TODO: This will not show
}
```

In addition; **`FIXME`**, **`???`**, **`????`**, **`!!!!`** do the same.

[image: TODO]

Comment: Ah, this makes sense as to why my TODOs, which I always put INSIDE the functions, never showed up. Well, that's dumb... :/ Thanks for this.

Comment: 1. In my Xcode 4.6, they work even *inside* of a function. 2. Only three exclamation marks (`!!!`) are needed, instead of four. 3. `MARK` also works. 4. The colon is compulsory. See http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Apr/msg00360.html

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use Xcode's search feature. If you mark your code with `// TODO:...`, you can search the entire project for `// TODO` and generate a nice list of tasks.

Also, note that comments starting with `// TODO:` or `// FIXME:` that are outside the scope of any method will appear in the method popup menu, just like `#pragma mark` lines.